# Precedence rules - Trouble using brackets and division with srand to get a float number

Tags: c, random, floating-point, double, srand

I am trying to manipulate `srand` so that srand returns a decimal number by division. But it's not working. My Code doesn't return a decimal number even though precedence rules should prioritize brackets before division.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    double save;

    srand(time(NULL));

    save = (rand() % 100)/ 10;

    printf("%f", save);

    return 0;
}
```

However this code works fine, but I'm not happy with the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    double save;

    srand(time(NULL));

    save = rand() % 100;

    save = save / 10;

    printf("%f", save);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain this and give a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem of this code:

```
double save;
save = (rand() % 100) / 10;
```

is not in precedence of operators, but because of division by integral constant `10`. Try:

```
save = (rand() % 100) / 10.0;
```

yet in case you want to generate numbers from interval `<0; 10)` it would better to do:

```
save = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * 10.0;
```

which will yield more precise results that will also be more uniformly distributed :)

Comment: Thank you! that explains alot! but... could u explain why          `save = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * 9.9;`          is better than for instance                                                 `save = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX)) * 10;`

Comment: That is if im looking for a number that is, 0 <= number <=10, not 0 < number < 10,

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What makes you think that scaling down using `RAND_MAX + 1.0` produces less uniform distribution than `%` ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah, yah. You're right with that multiplication with `9.9`, it should be `10.0` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It has no relation with *Operator precedence*!
`rand()` returns `int` type and dividing it by an integer will also return `int` value. You have to cast `(rand() % 100)/ 10` to `double`

```
save = (double) (rand() % 100)/ 10;
```

In second case

```
save = rand() % 100;
```

promotes value obtained by `rand() % 100` to `double`. And then dividing `save` by `10` is giving you right answer, i,e, `double`.